# Corrupted Windows 8 MBR, recovery disk's repair tools fail

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, mbr

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit on an ASUS N56 Laptop. I was attempting to upgrade to Windows 8.1 and the installation was interrupted. Attempted System Restore, which didn't work. Long story short, I ended up corrupting my MBR and got stuck in an Automatic Recovery Loop.

Now, I've faced this problem before, what I usually do is boot using a windows 8 recovery disc or USB drive, access command prompt from the repair tools and fixmbr from there.

But this time around, no matter what I do, whenever I click on repair tools from the recovery disc or USB, it leads me to a blue screen with a cursor and the tools never load. I've even attempted using a Ubuntu Live Disc and LILO, but its not working, probably because windows 8 was improperly shutdown and Ubuntu cannot mount the discs.